# Python 3 Modules vs. filenames

Tags: python-3.x

What is the difference and relationship between module names and filenames  in Python 3?  Must a module name always be identical to the filename?

Answer (score 2):

A module\module_name can be one of these:

- file
- folder
- folder with **__init__.py** inside of it
- **__main__** module name (the file you just run...)
- you can change your module name or insert an object to ***sys.modules** that 
  will appear as a module

I hope this helps ...

Comment: so __main__ is analogous to the main class in a Java program that contains public static void main() ?  Can it be used to name a module? Such that I could have a file named "File" that contains a module named "Module" ?